# Combining lists into an arraylist (C#)

Tags: list, arraylist

I have a list and I want to copy three other lists into it.

```
// The main list
List<List<string>> list= new List<List<string>>();

// The lists which I want to combine
ArrayList sublist1= new ArrayList();;
ArrayList sublist2= new ArrayList();;
ArrayList sublist3= new ArrayList();;
```

What I tried is:

```
list[0].AddRange(sublist1);
list[0].AddRange(sublist2);
list[0].AddRange(sublist3);
```

It doesn't work because It is multidimensional list. I need this type of list for the future plans.

How can I accomplist it?

Comment: I suspect it doesn't work for *other* reasons (not creating instances, missing type-specificity, adding `sublist2` twice, etc).. what *is* the real code and what *is* the error message / exception / incorrect result / unexplained observed behavior? (And what is the desired result?)

Comment: It says `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: So there you have it. You need to pass in something conforming to `IEnumerable<string>`. `ArrayList` does not. Nothing to do with multidimensionalisms. Perhaps: `list[0].AddRange(sublist1.Cast<string>())` (make sure to "using" Linq) .. or better, well-type the "sublists" (e.g. `List<string> sublist1 = ..`).

Comment: Yes it worked! thanks @pst but I can't vote your comment for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments just use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`.
It has nothing to do about multidimensional arrays, just types mismatch.

Then you say `List<List<string>>` it basically means create list type, which will contain `List<string>` as items (the part in angle brackets), so you need to add them, not `ArrayList`s. Similarly `List<string>` means type of list which will contain `string` as items.

Answer (score 1):

change type of sublists to some `IEnumerable<string>` (string[] or `List<string>` or something else)

```
var sublist1 = new string[] {};
var sublist2 = new string[] {};
var sublist3 = new string[] {};
```

OR do cast

```
list[0].AddRange((IEnumerable<string>) sublist1);
list[0].AddRange((IEnumerable<string>) sublist2);
list[0].AddRange((IEnumerable<string>) sublist3);
```

Because you are trying to use AddRange method of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`
and the signature of this method is

```
public void AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

so it requires IEnumerable as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments, you need to pass a type that follows IEnumerable. For example, you can change your ArrayLists to List

```
// The main list
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

// The lists which I want to combine
var sublist1 = new List<string>();
var sublist2 = new List<string>();
var sublist3 = new List<string>();

list[0].AddRange(sublist1);
list[0].AddRange(sublist2);
list[0].AddRange(sublist3);
```